# entity framework - two people with the same data

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I want to map a two tables in entity framework 6 and need some help! It is for my chat application; I need to map user conversations into the database. Both group and private messages. For this question however, if you help me with the private messaging mapping, I should hopefully work out the group by myself :) anyway....

Each user can talk to any other user. They however share the same data, which is where I  am struggling a bit: how to set the keys to the exact same data without duplication. This is what I have so far:
*********EDIT - new code* *******

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace CodeFirstNewDatabaseSample
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using(var db = new PrivateMessageContext()) 
            {
                Console.Write("Enter message: ");
                var message = Console.ReadLine();
                var userFrom = "userFrom";
                var userTo = "userTo";
                var messageDetail = new PrivateMessageDetail(MessageDate = DateTime.Now, FromUser = userFrom, message = message);
                var pm = new PrivateMessageHeader { User1 = userFrom, User2 = userTo, TimeStamp = DateTime.Now }; 
                pm.Messages.Add(messageDetail);
                db.PrivateMessages.Add(pm);
                db.SaveChanges();

                // Display all Blogs from the database 
                foreach(var pmsg in db.PrivateMessages)
                {
                    var query = pmsg;
                    Console.WriteLine(pmsg.Message);
                }
                Console.ReadKey(); 
        }
    }
}
public class PrivateMessage
{
    public int PrivateMessageId { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

   // public int User1Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string user1 { get; set; }
   // public virtual User user1 { get; set; }
   public virtual string user2 { get; set; }
    //public int User1Id { get; set; }
   // public virtual User user2 { get; set; }
}
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
public class PrivateMessageContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<PrivateMessage> PrivateMessages { get; set; }
}
public class Send
{
 /*   void Send(userTo, userFrom, message) 
    {
        using (var db = new PrivateMessageContext()) {
            var query = from pm in db.PrivateMessages;
            foreach(var msg in pm)
            {
                var user1 = msg.user1;
                var user2 = msg.user2;
                if ( (user1==userTo && user2==userFrom) || (user1==userFrom && user2==userTo))
                {
                      msg.Message += message;
                      return;
                }
                else {
            // pair doesn't exist

                     var PrivateMessage = new PrivateMessage { user1 = userFrom; user2 = userTo; TimeStamp = DateTime.Now; Message = message; }; 
                     db.PrivateMessages.Add(PrivateMessage); 
                     db.SaveChanges(); 
                }
            }      
       }*/
}
```

}

I am now stuck on two things - how to make a callable class which checks if there is previous message history (the Send() ) and how to use the User username instead of strings...

Thank you

****update 3****

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using(var db = new PrivateMessageContext()) 
            {
                Console.Write("Enter message: ");
                var message = Console.ReadLine();
                var userFrom = "userFrom";
                var userTo = "userTo";
                var messageDetail = new PrivateMessageDetail(MessageDate = DateTime.Now, FromUser = userFrom, message = message);
                var pm = new PrivateMessageHeader { User1 = userFrom, User2 = userTo, TimeStamp = DateTime.Now, Message = messageDetail }; 
                db.PrivateMessages.Add(pm);
                db.SaveChanges();

                // Display all Blogs from the database 
                foreach(var pmsg in db.PrivateMessages)
                {
                    var query = pmsg;
                    Console.WriteLine(pmsg.Message);
                }
                Console.ReadKey(); 
        }
    }
}
public class PrivateMessageContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public DbSet<PrivateMessageHeader> PrivateMessages { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your problem is.  What do you mean by "they share the same data"?  There should be no duplication since two users can't send the same message

Comment: Hi Erik, I meant that I want the messages to all be saved inside the same Private message. So each message a user sends is appended to the previously sent messages, so an entire message history is saved.

By sharing the same data basically I mean that if user1 sends to user 2, they both get the message history from the same place, and they dont have two storages of the same message history. Anyway, I'm editing my question, as I've made some progress :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want is some kind of master/detail.  What you would do is create a PrivateMessageHeader type, and this would contain the participants in the private message.  Then you would have a PrivateMessageDetail type that would contain the actual messages.  There would be a 1 to many association between Header and details.

So something like this:

```
public class PrivateMessageHeader {
    public PrivateMessageHeader() { Messages = new List<PrivateMessageDetail>; }
    public int PrivateMessageHeaderId {get;set;}
    public DateTime ThreadTime {get;set;} // Date of the start of thread
    public string User1 {get;set;}
    public string User2 {get;set;}  // this could be made to a list to allow multiples

    public ICollection<PrivateMessageDetail> Messages {get;set;}
}

public class PrivateMessageDetail {
    public int PrivateMessageDetailId {get;set;}
    public DateTime MessageDate {get;set;}
    public string FromUser {get;set;} // Don't need ToUser, it's already in header
    public string Message {get;set;}

    public PrivateMessageHeader parent {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: thank you, I have editted an update, but why am I getting errors for the line 
var messageDetail = new PrivateMessageDetail(MessageDate = DateTime.Now, FromUser = userFrom, message = message); 
many thanks

Comment: @user2330270 - Since you don't say what error you're getting, I have no idea.  However, Entity framework requires that objects have parameterless constructors. If that's not your error, it will be eventually.

Comment: It has a problem with the constructor creating a new list:

Messages = new List<PrivateMessageDetail>

Do you need to do this in the constructor?